# Backbone.js - throws error

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am very basic level with backbone.js, i am trying to add couple of elements to body, for that is used this function, but i am getting the erros as "Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined" - what is wrong with my code?

error i am getting:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined"
```

HTML(template):

```
<script id="person" type="text/template">
    <strong><%= name %></strong><sup><%= age %></sup>
</script>
```

function:

```
(function($){

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
      name:'default name',
      age:'default age'
  }
});

var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Model    
});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'li',
    template:_.template($('#person').html()),
    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render:function(){
        $('body').append(this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())));
    }
});

var ncol = new Col({model:[{name:'abc',age:1},{name:'cdf',age:2},{name:'ghi',age:1}]});

var persons = new PersonView({model:ncol});

})(jQuery)
```

Any one help me to sort my issue..?

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly initializing your collection. The `Collection` constructor expects the initial models as an array, not an object. So instead of:

```
new Col({model:[
    {name:'abc',age:1},
    {name:'cdf',age:2},
    {name:'ghi',age:1}
]});
```

It should be:

```
new Col([
    {name:'abc',age:1},
    {name:'cdf',age:2},
    {name:'ghi',age:1}
]);
```

This may or may not be the cause your particular error, but that least this will cause some serious havoc.